# Calculate jaccard distance using scipy in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two separate lists as follows.

```
list1 =[[0.0, 0.75, 0.2], [0.0, 0.5, 0.7]]
list2 =[[0.9, 0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0, 0.8], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

I want to get a list1 x list2 jaccard distance matrix (i.e. the matrix includes 6 values: 2 x 3)

```
    For example;
[0.0, 0.75, 0.2] in list1 with all the three lists in list2
[0.0, 0.5, 0.7] in list1 with all the three lists in list2
```

I actually tried both `pdist` and `cdist`. However I get the following errors respectively; `TypeError: pdist() got multiple values for argument 'metric'` and `ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.`.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try : `np.atleast_2d` wrapping it with the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass to pdist a `m x n` 2D array. To construct it, you can use a simple nested loop.
You could probably do something like this :

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist

list1 =[[0.0, 0.75, 0.2], [0.0, 0.5, 0.7]]
list2 =[[0.9, 0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0, 0.8], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
distance = []
for elem1 in list1:
    for elem2 in list2:
        distance.append(dist.pdist([elem1,elem2], 'jaccard'))
```

You get your results in the `distance` array.